# Is a closed question "opened", or "re-opened"?

Tags: word-choice

If a question on a Stack Exchange site is closed and then that closure is reverted for the first time, is it "opened", or "re-opened"?

Natural intuition suggests "re-opened", even if it's the first time that a closure has been reverted. Possibly because a question starts out in an "open" state by default.

Comment: I agree, for whatever that's worth. There doesn't seem to be a standard usage across disciplines however.

Answer (score 1):

If the question has been closed, it implies that it was opened in the first time.

Re-opened seems compulsory.